# How to Show The image from one view to other view in Asp.Net WebApi MVC4?

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

HI all i have some images which i am retrieving dynamically and displaying in a view like this

here is my controller

```
    private ProductEntities products = new ProductEntities();
    public List<ProductItems> GetAllProducts()
    {
        var items = new List<ProductItems>();
        var records = products.Products.ToList();
        foreach (var item in records)
        {
            ProductItems model = new ProductItems();
            model.ProductID = item.ProductId;
            model.ProductName = item.ProductName;
            model.ImageURL = item.ImageURL;
            items.Add(model);
        }
        return items;
    }
```

and this is my index page view

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("/api/ProductDetails", function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (idx, ele) {
                $("<img/>").attr({ src: ele.ImageURL }).appendTo("#makeMeScrollable");
                $("#makeMeScrollable").append('<h4><a href="#">' + ele.ProductName + '</a></h4>');

            });
        });
    });      

</script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Products</h1>
<div class="rightsection_main">
    <div class="img_main" id="makeMeScrollable">            

       </div>
   </div>
  </body>
```

now what i want is when ever an user clicks on a image i have to pass the ID of the image to my method in my apicontroller and i have to display that image in another view ..how do i pass my image to another view and Id to my api/controller  action

i have to pass my ProductID to this method

```
  public IEnumerable<ProductItems> ProductDeatils(long ProductID)
    {
        var productdeatils = products.ExecuteStoreQuery<ProductItems>("GetProductDetail @ProductID ", new SqlParameter("@ProductID", ProductID));           
        return productdeatils ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that API actions do not return views. They are used to serialize models using some format such as JSON or XML. So when you are saying that you want to use the ProductDeatils API action to display a view, this doesn't make much sense. Views are returned by standard ASP.NET MVC controller actions returning ActionResults. So let's see how to set this up.

Let's suppose that you have the following API controllers:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    private ProductEntities products = new ProductEntities();
    public IEnumerable<ProductItems> Get()
    {
        return products.Products.ToList().Select(item => new ProductItems
        {
            ProductID = item.ProductId,
            ProductName = item.ProductName,
            ImageURL = item.ImageURL
        });
    }
}

public class ProductDetailsController : ApiController
{
    private ProductEntities products = new ProductEntities();
    public ProductItems Get(long id)
    {
        return products.ExecuteStoreQuery<ProductItems>(
            "GetProductDetail @ProductID ", 
            new SqlParameter("@ProductID", id)
        );
    }
}
```

Alright, now we will need standard ASP.NET MVC controller that will serve the views:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Products()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult ProductDetail(long id)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var productDetailUrl = Url.RouteUrl(
                "DefaultApi", 
                new { httproute = "", controller = "productdetails", id = id },
                Request.Url.Scheme
            );
            var model = client
                .GetAsync(productDetailUrl)
                .Result
                .Content
                .ReadAsAsync<ProductItems>()
                .Result;
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

and the respective view for showing the list of products and the detail of a product when a link is clicked:

`~/Views/Home/Products.cshtml`:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Products</h1>
    <div class="rightsection_main">
        <div class="img_main" id="makeMeScrollable">            

        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var productsUrl = '@Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { httproute = "", controller = "products" })';
        var productDetailUrl = '@Url.Action("productdetail", "home", new { id = "__id__" })';

        $.getJSON(productsUrl, function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (idx, product) {
                $('<img/>').attr({ src: product.ImageURL }).appendTo('#makeMeScrollable');
                $('#makeMeScrollable').append(
                    $('<h4/>').html(
                        $('<a/>', {
                            href: productDetailUrl.replace('__id__', product.ProductID),
                            text: product.ProductName
                        })
                    )
                );
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and `~/Views/Home/ProductDetail.cshtml`:

```
@model ProductItems
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>ProductDetail</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ProductName)</h4>
    <img src="@Model.ImageURL">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ...i am geting an error saying "One or more errors occurred." @ var model = client
                .GetAsync(productDetailUrl)
                .Result
                .Content
                .ReadAsAsync<ProductItems>()
                .Result; in my hone controller

Comment: Is your API controller action invoked? What are the errors? Did you try debugging your code?

Comment: ....yes the action is invoked but after returning the data to the controller in my Home controller i am geting this error

Comment: So what's inside the exception? Did you look at the InnerException? The error message you have posted in your comment doesn't allow for knowing what the problem is. Please debug your code and inspect the details of this exception.

Comment: You didn't get an exception but it's throwing an error? How is this even possible :-) Do you know how to debug code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17586/discussion-between-anil-and-darin-dimitrov)

Comment: this is the exception i am geting @Darin Dimitrov    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize JSON array (i.e. [1,2,3]) into type 'ProductDetails.Models.ProductItems'.
The deserialized type must be an array or implement a collection interface like IEnumerable, ICollection or IList.
To force JSON arrays to deserialize add the JsonArrayAttribute to the type. Line 1, position 1.